# .NET Web Service: .asmx?WSDL vs .wsdl

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

This is probably a stupid question. I don't know anything about Web Service but I have to work on this existing web service.

What is the difference between club.asmx?wsdl vs club.wsdl ?

I noticed they are similar, but club.wsdl has more stuff in it.

Aren't they generated automatically from the .cs code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

club.asmx?wsdl is a request to the service to generate and return a WSDL.

club.wsdl is just a reference to a file on your web server. Presumably it contains the WSDL that is meant to be exposed to customers.

Comment: Thanks John. Yes apparently club.wsdl is the complete file. But why are they different?